Impossible to import regions from Pygal maps
I'm trying to plot regional data on a map of France, but if I do one of these :
import pygal_maps_fr
from pygal_maps_fr import aggregate_regions

import pygal_maps_fr
from pygal_maps_fr import Regions

then I get the message "ImportError: cannot import name 'aggregate_regions' from 'pygal_maps_fr'" (or : ImportError: cannot import name 'Regions' from 'pygal_maps_fr')
Please how can I get these regions ?
By the way, many websites advise to write from pygal.maps.fr (instead of from pygal_maps_fr), but in my case this name is not recognized
